# Unity : project works in editor but black screen when build

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox, augmented-reality

I'm on a project using Unity 2019 LTS and some unity SDK / package:

- Mapbox SDK
- DreamWorld SDK (the SDK of my AR headset)
- some other default AR packages (Foundation, Subsystem)

I would like to reused the Mapbox World-scale AR example in order to implement the possibility to move the scene according my AR headset position.

To do so, I removed the default main camera of the example (in AR Root) and added instead a the camera for my headset, as explained in the headset's docs ([DW Developer Kit SDK](https://www.dreamworldvision.com/developers)).

Here are some pictures of what I've done:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

No here's my problem: when I run the project in the editor with the player mode, all works perfectly fine and I see the camera rotation following the position of my AR headset.

Therefore, if I try to build the project, I cannot the see the "view" of the camera. I know that the project run because I still can see the overlay menu provides by the Mapbox World-scale example but not my camera.

Editor :

[image]

Build :

[image]

I searched online to find some solution to my issue but I only found some answer about building to Android and iPhone while I trying to build on my laptop.

The fact I see a black screen (and the overlay) seems to me that Unity cannot find a camera to show me the scene.

I just started using Unity, so it is possible that I missed an obvious thing but I don't know what.

If someone as any idea of what my problem is...

Comment: I can recomment LogViewer (free) for Unity. Once added to your scene, run your build and draw a circle with pressed mouse-button to get a console with logs. There may be some errors in Build that are not present in Editor.
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/log-viewer-12047

Comment: @KYL3R I installed it but  can't see the Logs when I try to make a circle with my mouse (right and left click press)

Comment: You need to add it to your main Scene. In Unity Menu: "Reporter->Create" will add a gameobject with the Reporter Script attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## General Solution

Just Remove and Re-Add your Main Scene under the menu **File / Build Settings / Scene In Build.**

Use **Add Open Scenes** Button to re-add the scene.

Answer (score 0):

In case the suggestion from the comments with the In-Game logs does not work, you can check the external log file.
According to https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html
it is found under "C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\LocalLow\CompanyName\ProductName\Player.log"
CompanyName and ProductName are two names you can project somewhere in the unity project settings but there are default values.